# Como habilitar e desabilitar textarea com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Após efetuar uma busca no Site, encontrei essa [pergunta com solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56659/como-habilitar-e-desabilitar-campos-ao-clicar-em-bot%C3%A3o), mas a solução é em `jquery`!

Ao escolher opção X preciso que um campo em especifico fique desabilitado e só volte a ser habilitado caso outra opção seja acionada!

Preciso dessa solução em `JavaScript` *(todo projeto é em JavaScript)*.

```html
<button id='btn_habilitar'>Habilita</button>
<button id='btn_desabilitar'>Desabilita</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id='obs' placeholder='Observação!'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O que é preciso para bloquear/desabilitar uma *textarea* (ou *input*) é o atributo/propriedade `disabled`. Assim colocando-o com `setAttribute` ou removendo-o com `removeAttribute` vais obter o resultado que queres. Um exemplo seria:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('obs');
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
    if (id == 'btn_desabilitar') textarea.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    else if (id == 'btn_habilitar') textarea.removeAttribute('disabled');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eo3nLfpp/

ou simplesmente via propiedade do elemento DOM

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('obs');
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
    textarea.disabled = id == 'btn_desabilitar';
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eo3nLfpp/1/

Comment: Você não acha ruim disparar o evento em toda tela ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues neste caso é um exemplo. Mas de modo mais geral depende do caso e depende do tipo de evento. Todos os eventos tem capture e bubbling. Quando se usa delegação é isso que se faz.

Answer (score 6):

Basta usar o atributo [`document.getElementById("id").disabled`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_disabled.asp):

```js
function toggle(enable) {
  document.getElementById("obs").disabled = enable;
}
```

```html
<button id='btn_habilitar' onclick="toggle(false)">Habilita</button>
<button id='btn_desabilitar' onclick="toggle(true)">Desabilita</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id='obs' placeholder='Observação!'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer assim:

### Exemplo:

```js
var btn_habilitar = document.getElementById('btn_habilitar');
var btn_desabilitar = document.getElementById('btn_desabilitar');
var obs = document.getElementById('obs');


btn_habilitar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  obs.disabled = false;
});

btn_desabilitar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  obs.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<button id='btn_habilitar'>Habilita</button>
<button id='btn_desabilitar'>Desabilita</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id='obs' placeholder='Observação!'></textarea>
```

### Detalhe:

**Disabled** não passa o valor para o formulário, além de não poder editar.

**Readonly** envia o valor para o formulário e também não pode editar.