# Selecionar button com jQuery e habilitar input de um form

Tags: jquery, html5, formulário

Boa tarde pessoal,

estou tentando implementar a seguinte solução:

**Ao clicar no elemento button eu quero que o campo input seja habilitado.**

Mas ao clicar no button nada acontece. Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar qual o problema do meu código?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Pain Free</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Site voltado para manipular doencas de pacientes que utiizando o app do pain free">
    <meta name="Laura" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
</head>

<body>
 <section id="profile_doctor">

        <div class="container_profile_doctor">

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <img src="doctor.png" alt="avatar doctor" id="avatar_profile_doctor" 
                  class="rounded mx-auto d-block"
                  width="180" height="180"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <form  action="" method="POST">

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="doctor_name" disabled="true" placeholder="Nome">
                  </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_edit_profile_doctor">Editar</button>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="occupation" class="form-control" id="doctor_occupation" disabled="true" placeholder="Profissão">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_edit_profile_doctor">Editar</button>
                </div>
           </form>
            </div>


        </section>

<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
```

**Código jQuery**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $(':button').click(function()
    {
        var inputText = $('.form-control').attr('disabled',true);
    }
    );
  }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Mude o .attr('disabled',true) para removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: Habilitou da primeira vez e voltou a desabilitar. Agora não habilita mais.

Comment: Tente isso: $('.form-control').toggle('disable');

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como habilitar e desabilitar campos ao clicar em botão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56659/como-habilitar-e-desabilitar-campos-ao-clicar-em-bot%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Obrigada pela ajuda pessoal, consegui resolver utilizando o seguinte código.**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $(':button').click(function()
    {
       $("input").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    );

    $('#btn_save_doctor').click(function()
        {
          $("input").prop("disabled", true);
        }
      );
  }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Só tenha em mente que usando o seletor por ID tipos assim ` $('#btn_save_doctor')` como vc fez, se vc tiver 10 btns, com 10 IDs diferentes vc vai precisar de 10x mais linhas de código, algo que é no mínimo uma má pratica.... pense nisso...

Comment: Mas eu só preciso habilitar os campos com um botão e desabilitar com outro botão. Mas obrigada pela dica de toda forma :)

Answer (score 3):

Seu JS tinha algumas coisa estranhas, a primeira era que onde estava `.attr('disabled', true)` deveria ser `.attr('disabled', false)`.

Depois o seu `button` era `type=submit` e deveria ser `type=button`, e tb quando clicava em qualquer um dos botões os dois campos estavam ficando editáveis, e não apenas o campo referente ao botão mais próximo, para corrigir isso eu usei `$(this).parent().find('.form-control')` para pegar apenas o `input` próximo ao `button`. E os seus botões estão com o mesmo `ID`, isso deve ser sempre evitado, não use o mesmo `ID` para mais de um elemento, dica do @VictorCarnaval

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
 <style>

 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <section id="profile_doctor">

  <div class="container_profile_doctor">

   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <img src="doctor.png" alt="avatar doctor" id="avatar_profile_doctor" class="rounded mx-auto d-block"
      width="180" height="180" />
    </div>
   </div>

   <form action="" method="POST">

    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="doctor_name" disabled="true"
       placeholder="Nome">
     </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_edit_profile_doctor">Editar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="occupation" class="form-control" id="doctor_occupation" disabled="true"
       placeholder="Profissão">
     </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_edit_profile_pro">Editar</button>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>


 </section>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('button').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.form-control').attr('disabled', false);
   });
  });
 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Os dois elementos `button` possuem o mesmo **id**.

Comment: @VictorCarnaval valeu a dica, mais um erro para a lista, esse eu não tinha percebido rss

Comment: @VictorCarnaval editei e coloquei os créditos ;)

Comment: Boa @hugocsl :)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa remover o `type="submit"` dos seus botões para evitar de enviar o formulário. Além disto, deveria ser `false` o valor para o atributo `disabled` no seu script.